# Angular 2 submit dynamic component

Tags: angular

I'm creating dynamic component starting from a json coming from the server.
To do this, I used the example in the official guide 
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

```
loadComponent(requiredFields) {
    let bankInput : InputItem;
    let bankItem = requiredFields[0];
    if (bankItem.nature == "text"){
        bankInput = new InputItem(InputTextComponent,bankItem);

    }


    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(bankInput.component);

    let viewContainerRef = this.inputHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<InputBankComponent>componentRef.instance).data = bankInput.data;


  }
```

Obviously this is a snippet supporting only text.

Is all working fine, but now I have to submit the generated fields to the server.

How can I put the generated fields into a form?
What is the better way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the official doc about [forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) ?

You can also read the [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) to dynamically build a form, here is an example (using an already existing validator) :

```
this.form = this.fb.group({

   Address1: [address.Address1, this.validator.buildAddressValidators()],
   Address2: [address.Address2, this.validator.buildAddressValidators()],
   Address3: [address.Address3, this.validator.buildAddressValidators()],
   Address4: [address.Address4, this.validator.buildAddressValidators()],

   ZipCode: [address.ZipCode, this.validator.buildZipCodeValidators(true)],
   City: [address.City, this.validator.buildCityValidators(true)]
});
```

Comment: yes, but I'm stuck on it. I cannot understand how to add component to a form group dynamically. I keep getting the error ormControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Comment: Thanks but my situation is a little different because the input are created at button click, so i m not able to use formbuilder.
Basically i have a button that on click read a json with description of the field to add and i have to render them. 

With viewcontainerref, i am able to add a input, but i dont understand how to insert the created component ina form to validate and submit.. 

Hope that now is more clear...